# Google App Engine Java app couldn't find javac?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm learning to use Google App Engine, I installed it in Netbeans, the project works, but when I clicked on "Deploy To Google App Engine", I got the following error :

Beginning server interaction for ...

0% Creating staging directory

5% Scanning for jsp files.

8% Compiling jsp files.

11% Compiling java files.

Error Details:

Apr 20, 2010 3:51:23 PM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile

INFO: Built File: \PayPal_Monitor.jsp

java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot find javac executable based on java.home, tried "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javac.exe" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\bin\javac.exe"

Unable to update app: cannot find javac executable based on java.home, tried "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javac.exe" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\bin\javac.exe"

Please see the logs [C:\Users\NM\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg3946701335172983337.log] for further information.

The file "javac.exe" is in : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin

How can I add it to "java.home" ? I'm using Win Vista, and I tried to add it from "System -> Environment Variables", but there is no "java.home" in there. Where can I find it ?

Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change appcfg.cmd to:

```
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin\java" -cp
"%~dp0\..\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar" com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg %*
```

Read [here.](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1226)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not too particular about Netbeans, I would suggest using the Google App engine plugin for Eclipse for developing on the app engine. Its really great and provides a fantastic debugging experience.